# Unity Navmesh Obstacle faces a different direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, navmesh

[image]

My NAVMESH OBSTACLE faces a different direction from my Buildings as the picture shows. How do i correct this?

Comment: This looks like the model isn't parallel to axes.

Comment: @shingo Do you think that's where the problem is coming from?

Comment: I think it's from the tool that created this model. I mean you may rotate it then export it again.

Comment: If you have difficulty to modify the model, you can put the model as a child GameObject to the Obstacle.

Comment: Hmmm....thank you sir. I'll try that out